# Calculate masklen from netmask string in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ip-address, cidr, netmask

I know this question has been asked before for different languages, but as far as I can see it relies on flow control ("for loops") and/or esoteric Perl functions.

So in PostgreSQL, I'm trying to write a database migration to convert our network information stored as `text` into proper `inet` types. Suppose my 'Foo' table has two columns, "address" which stores the IP address itself, and "netmask" which stores the "netmask" (e.g. `'255.255.255.0'`). I want to insert these into the single 'ip' field of a new 'Bar' table as a single `inet`-type column.

So far what I've got is pretty straightforward for converting the IP, but I'm struggling on the mask length. I assume it'll look something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO bar(ip)
    SELECT set_masklen(address::inet, calculate_masklen_from_netmask(netmask))
    FROM foo
;
```

... but I have no idea how to define that function `calculate_masklen_from_netmask` since I can't use flow control structures in a statement-based language.

Answer (score 1):

You can (ab)use `inet_merge` for that purpose. Use `masklen(inet_merge(netmask, inet '255.255.255.255')`.

In your case you may more cleanly get the full address using `inet_merge(address & netmask, address | ~netmask)` (but avoid using `netmask` as a name as it is already a function). You can omit `& netmask`, I it included for completeness/clarity. You could just do `inet_merge(address, address | ~netmask)`